# Boolean variable not declaring?

Tags: javascript, css, html, boolean

Rewriting a program written in Unity with HTML5, CSS and JavaScript is kinda tricky. One thing, that's seriously messing with me right now, is I made a variable called `isGame`, with a value of either `true` or `false`.

The code initially gives it a value of `false`, and at certain pages (visa vie a `pageNumber` variable with a numeric value) it is supposed to be `false`. Not sure what I'm typing wrong or what, but it's not working.

Here's the code:

```
function setContent() {
  if (pageNumber == 1) {
    var isGame = false;
    document.getElementById("ng_audiocontainer").innerHTML = '<audio autoplay="autoplay"><source id="ng_intro" src="audio/example"></audio>';
    currentAudio = document.getElementById("ng_intro");
    document.getElementById("ng_body").innerHTML = '<img src="images/example.png" id="ng_logo">';
    document.getElementById("ng_lipsbutton").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

The `setContent()` function, as you can see, fills an HTML block with content, and autoplays an audio. It's basically an interactive learning tool thing, with a left and right arrow. The right increments and calls `setContent()`, and the left decrements and calls `setContent()`, creating a sort-of ghetto-rigged pagination.

The only issue I'm having is, that the `isGame` variable is not being declared as `false` or `true`, and simply remains what I initially declare it as at the top of my script. It doesn't make any sense, because I wrote it the same as I wrote the page number. Help?

Sorry if this is TLDR, not sure how to sum up.

---

EDIT:

Here's some more details. At the very top of my script (which is internal by the way, since this is basically going to be pasted into a websites HTML) I declare the `pageNumber` as `0` and the `isGame` as `false`.

```
var pageNumber = 0;
var isGame = false;

function setContent() {
```

Following is of course the function above. The `isGame` is called, when certain things are clicked on, some being 'wrong' and some 'right', but I only want them to be able to react to being clicked on, when `isGame == true`. Here's that code:

```
function rightLetter() {
  if (isGame == true) { 
    pageNumber++;
    setContent(); 
  }
```

Comment: You did not post the complete function. But because you're re-declaring `isGame` with `var` inside the function, any declaration of `isGame` outside the script will be hidden and not affected by code in the function.

Comment: well you declare it with `var` so.....

Comment: Generally though, such variable should be declared/initialized outside the function.

Comment: Can you post more code, to show where you initially set the variable and where you are checking it's value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are overwriting your `isGame` var every time you call the function. Try this:

```
var isGame = false; // Declare your boolean var first

function setContent() {

    if (pageNumber == 1) {

        isGame = true; // Update your var here, to true or false
        document.getElementById("ng_audiocontainer").innerHTML = '<audio autoplay="autoplay"><source id="ng_intro" src="audio/example"></audio>';
        currentAudio = document.getElementById("ng_intro");
        document.getElementById("ng_body").innerHTML = '<img src="images/example.png" id="ng_logo">';
        document.getElementById("ng_lipsbutton").style.display = "none";

    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the eff you were downvoted, your solution worked.

Comment: neither I do :(